# Сборка PHP+ReactJS используя WebPack

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, webpack

Есть такой скрипт для вебпака

```js
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/dist"),
    filename: "index-bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

сейчас страницу, которую им собирал, нужно переносить на сайт и подключать к ней PHP, не знаю как собирать PHP WebPack'ом

Comment: `php` вебпаком не собирают)))))

Comment: `php` вообще собирать не нужно, вы имеете представление что такое и зачем нужен `php`?

Comment: Что такое PHP знаю. Речь не о том. У меня сейчас в качестве шаблона для страницы используется index.html, и обрабатывается она HtmlWebpackPlugin. Если я пытаюсь использовать в качестве шаблона index.php, в котором у меня подключаются header и footer из CMS, то ничего у меня не работает. На выходе я все равно имею файл index.html, и, естественно, php там не работает

Comment: Все правильно, работает как и ожидалось, у вас и никогда не будет это с php работать